# A mathematician's coffee alphametic

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, alphametic

Alfréd Rényi, a Hungarian mathematician, said that a mathematician is a machine for turning coffee into theorems. It's believed that his mention was about his colleague, Paul Erdős, the celebrated mathematician.

How much coffee had he drunken for his theorems? I think that he would drink 3 cups of coffee per theorem. :-)

```
  COFFEE
  COFFEE
+ COFFEE
--------
 THEOREM
```

Comment: That is an astonishingly efficient mathematician! (or trivial theorems)

Comment: This may be more obvious to some - but are we assuming that two letters can't represent the same digit? E.g. can R and M both be 7?

Comment: @frodoskywalker I agree. He was very prolific.
As for ordinary mathematicians, the truth about coffee is:
COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE
+ COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE 
+ COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE + COFFEE = THEOREM.

Comment: @P.-S.Park - That is indeed another way to turn multiple COFFEEs into a THEOREM, where COFFEE=210088 and THEOREM=3781584. Per the standard rules (each letter represents a single base 10 digit, different letters represent different digits, and the first letter of each word represents a non-zero digit), the only ways to turn COFFEE into THEOREM are COFFEE+COFFEE+COFFEE=THEOREM (one solution), COFFEE+COFFEE+COFFEE+COFFEE=THEOREM (four solutions), and COFFEE+COFFEE+...+COFFEE=THEOREM (18 COFFEEs, one solution).

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes, it's another way. Of course, the unit of measure is a barrel.

Comment: Can you please answer codemoose's question, namely : Can two letters represent the same digit? E.g. can R and M both be 7?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal No. The standard rule for alphametic is that different letters are different digits and the same letters are the same digits.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Letter values:

> C = 8, O = 3, F = 1, E = 9, T = 2, H = 4, R = 5, M = 7.

The equation:

> ```
>    831199
>    831199
>  + 831199
>  --------
>   2493597
> ```

Comment: How did you figure out the F or R? I couldn't get passed the M and E.

Comment: @KevinVoorn In the second column (O + O + O = E), you can see that if you had a number "carried" from the third column, the only carried number that would let you make Ox3 = E is 3. That can't be carried, as the maximum number you could make is 27 (9x3). So there can be *no* carried numbers there, meaning that O x 3 must be equal to E. That being the case, the only way that (F + F + F = O) could be true in the third column is if *it* had no carried numbers as well... If that makes sense.

Comment: It makes a lot of sense, thanks. I couldn't figure out how to get to the second E to get an answer, but now I got it as well :)

Comment: @EFrog, actually the `3xO=E` can be: 1) no carry from previous column => `O=3`, 2) carry 1 from previous column => `O=6`, 3) carry 2 from previous column => `O = 9`.  The second case implies that `F=5` and `R=7`, but `M` is already 7, so it can't be. The third case cannot happen because `E` is already 9.

Answer (score 13):

Well, first, we can determine E, since $E*11*3 = 100's + 10*E + change$.   Only number that fits is $E = 9, M = 7$. (Another way to think of it is to take each number times 3, add the digits and figure out which one matches; 9*3=27, 2+7=9)

Now, O and F are interesting, since the 10's of $F*11*3 = O$ and $3*O + (3*F \% 100) = 9$.  If O = 3, then F<=3, since it can't rollover to the hundreds. If F = 1, then we have no rollover. So, $O = 3, F = 1, R = 5$

So, that just leaves us with $3*C = TH$ without repeating a digit. C >= 7, since it has to be 2 digits and 1 is already taken. 8 works, since 24 is good. So, $C = 8, T = 2, H = 4$

Answer (score 9):

Noting that 3*E gives a different result in the first two columns, there must be an overflow i.e. E is greater than 3. This overflow can only be 1 or 2 (you cannot get more than 27 from tripling a single digit), and in the second column 3*E + overflow => E. This means 2*E + overflow (which is 1 or 2) equals either 10 or 20. E=9 is the only number which satisfies this, so E=9, M=7:

```
  COFF99
  COFF99
+ COFF99
--------
 TH9OR97
```

seeing that 3*O + (overflow from 3*F) = 9, O=3 and the overflow is zero (the overflow could only have been 0, 1 or 2, and only 0 is compatible with the result being divisible by 3).

```
  C3FF99
  C3FF99
+ C3FF99
--------
 TH93R97
```

but 3*F + (overflow from 3*F, which we know is 0) = 3, so F=1

```
  C31199
  C31199
+ C31199
--------
 TH93597
```

which also gives R=5. Now 3*C = TH. T can only be 1 or 2, and 1 is taken. T=2. To give an overflow of 2, C must be greater than 6. But 7 and 9 are already taken, so C=8, forcing H=4

```
  831199
  831199
+ 831199
--------
 2493597
```

Comment: _the overflow could only have been 0, 1 or 2, and only 0 is compatible with the result being divisible by 3_. No, all overflows are compatible with the result being divisible by 3. That's because `3xO` can also overflow. `3x3 = 9`, `3x6+1=19` and `3x9+2=29` all fit the `3xO+(overflow from 3xf)=9` (`=` here being congruency). The actual reason `O=3` is [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/8336/a-mathematicians-coffee-cryptarithm#comment25718_8337).

Comment: @Shahbaz You're right, not sure how I missed that. I will revise it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that a letter can have the same value as another letter, these are some lazy solutions.

> T = 1, H = 2, C = 4, E = F = M = O = R = 0
>  T = 1, H = 5, C = 5, E = F = M = O = R = 0
>  T = 1, H = 8, C = 6, E = F = M = O = R = 0
>  T = 2, H = 1, C = 7, E = F = M = O = R = 0
>  T = 2, H = 4, C = 8, E = F = M = O = R = 0
>  T = 2, H = 7, C = 9, E = F = M = O = R = 0

Comment: If you allow duplicate values, there are 40 solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Since the 'normal' solutions have all been found, have the brute force method:

Python2:

```
for c in xrange(333333,1000000):
    t=3*c 
    theorem=str(t)
    coffee=str(c)
    if theorem[2]!=theorem[5]:continue
    if theorem[5]!=coffee[5]:continue
    if coffee[4]!=coffee[5]:continue
    if coffee[2]!=coffee[3]:continue
    if coffee[1]!=theorem[3]:continue
    if len(set(coffee))!=4:continue
    if len(set(theorem))!=6:continue
    if len(set(coffee+theorem))!=8:continue
    print coffee,theorem
```